# Accidently added One Step sanitizer to my brew batch! Am I good or will I die?

Tags: ginger-beer, sanitizer, batch-size

I made a batch of ginger beer and brewing it hard at 5 and a half gallons. The fault came when I accidentally added a half-gallon of water with One Step in it to the batch before fermenting. It was originally a 1 gallon before I cleaned all my stuff,

I totally forgot I had it in it. Should I be concerned?

It doesn't seem to be stopping the fermentation and it is going very well.  To add, before I added the half I filled it the rest of the way making it a gallon, not realizing what I had done.

Answer (score 1):

So I just looked up the SDS sheet on it, and the ECOCleansers website.

[https://www.ecologiccleansers.com/products/one-step/](http://ecocleansers)

It seems that the principle sanitizing function is to create hydrogen peroxide, and the minerals left behind are typical levels found in many tap waters.

I don’t want to say yes it’s safe, but there is your basic information about the product.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the FAQ for One Step](http://www.onestepsani.com/faq.html)

As answered by @Escoce, once it is used it should be safe.

Hydrogen peroxide will decompose into water and oxygen. Maybe your ginger beer yeast gets a boost from the extra oxygen.